# Laravel Routes for Facebook Login

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm sorta kinda new again on the programming scene. I did some php back in college but I haven't touched it ever since and now I'm working on a side project. I'm Trying to create a simple app that will use Laravel and Facebook Login as the only source of logging into the app.

I did found some tutorials on how to do this but it seems to be outdated. (src = http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/)

It seems to be all working until the Route.php part.

I have this code under the route.php

```
    Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});

Route::get('login/fb', function() {
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'),
        'scope' => 'email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends' ,
    );
    return Redirect::away($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
});

Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {
    $code = Input::get('code');
    if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

    $me = $facebook->api('/me');

    dd($me);
});
```

In the said tutorial, I'm being asked to access the login/fb of the route. I tried doing this by accessing localhost/myapp/public/login/fb and it gave me an error

Whoops! Something went wrong

I tried to set the debug => true and I got a more puzzling set of errors

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#11 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:5465
#10 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:4794
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:4782
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:4774
#7 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:706
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:687
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:7440
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:8047
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:7994
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:10615
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\bootstrap\compiled.php:648
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in D:\Xampp\htdocs\GrabATable\public\index.php:49
```

Can someone point to me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: None of the routes are working? Did you include the Facebook library on the top of the routes file? Can you access localhost/myapp/public/

Comment: It's only this route that's not working. I'm not sure what you mean by "include the Facebook library" but I used a composer to download the Facebook SDK and it's in the Vendor folder already. I can access the public/ it returns Hello World.

Comment: can you `dd($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));` ?